# Function to change traffic light image to subsequent color error

Tags: javascript, html, image, traffic

I have an image element, and three images (*Red.png*, *Amber.png*, *Green.png*). I want my code to change the image element to the next image by clicking on it.

```html
<img src="Red.png" id="toggleImage" onclick="toggleImage()">
```

```js
function toggleImage() {
    var img1 = "Red.png";
    var img2 = "Amber.png";
    var img3 = "Green.png";
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('toggleImage');
    if (imgElement.src = img1) {
        imgElement.src = img2;
    }
    if (imgElement.src = img2) {
        imgElement.src = img3;
    }
    if (imgElement.src = img3) {
        imgElement.src = img1
    }
}
```

When the traffic light starts as Red.png and I click on it, it doesn't change.

When it starts as Amber.png and I click on it, it turns into Red.png and doesn't change again.

When it starts as Green.png it changes to Red.png upon clicking but clicking again doesn't change anything. I have tried it as an else if condition but it doesn't work, instead it changes to Amber.png, not red.

Comment: You need to write `imgElement.src == img1` instead of `imgElement.src = img1`. If you use a single `=` it is not a comparision but an assignment.

Comment: If/else is mandatory. Otherwise multiple if statements will be true and the result not what you want/expect.

Answer (score 1):

Use else if, as the original if method was too fast for human eye.

```js
function toggleImage() {
    var img1 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Red_Circle%28small%29.svg/1024px-Red_Circle%28small%29.svg.png";
    var img2 = "https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/310000/nahled/yellow-circle.png";
    var img3 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/LACMTA_Circle_Green_Line.svg/1024px-LACMTA_Circle_Green_Line.svg.png";
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('toggleImage');
  
    if (imgElement.src == img1) {
      // Red to Yellow
      imgElement.src = img2;
    }
    else if (imgElement.src == img2) {
      // Yellow to Green
      imgElement.src = img3;
    }
    else if (imgElement.src == img3) {
      // Green to Red
      imgElement.src = img1;
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

```html
<img id="toggleImage" onclick="toggleImage()" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: black;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Red_Circle%28small%29.svg/1024px-Red_Circle%28small%29.svg.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('img').on({
    'click': function() {
         document.querySelector('span').textContent = $(this).attr('src');
         var src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'image-photo/red-traffic-light-city-street-600w-425010472.jpg')
             ? 'image-vector/green-traffic-light-isolated-on-260nw-1539482378.jpg'
             : 'image-photo/red-traffic-light-city-street-600w-425010472.jpg';
         $(this).attr('src', src);
     }
});
```

```css
#img1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<base href="https://image.shutterstock.com/">
<img id="img1" src="image-photo/red-traffic-light-city-street-600w-425010472.jpg" height="300" width="300">
<span></span>
```

Hope this may help you understand how it will work. Work around yourself to achieve whatever you want.